# Are "grammatical words" the same thing as "function words"?

Tags: functions

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word) on wikipedia is a bout "function words", which are

> words that have little lexical meaning or have ambiguous meaning and express grammatical relationships among other words within a sentence, or specify the attitude or mood of the speaker

so I'd be tempted to say that "function words" is synonymous with "grammtical words". The linked page does use "grammatical words" as well, but it never explicitly states they are the same thing.

I wanted to confirm, just in case I'm missing some minor shade.

Comment: Grammar is about the way words are put together, so a single word can't be described as 'grammatical'.

Comment: My advice to you is to ignore the term 'functional word'. All words can be assigned a function in constituent analysis. The Wiki article is just a joke -- ignore it.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the term ["parts of speech"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech)?   The article you linked to seems to be talking about a linguitics term rather than something that is specific to the English language.  Not sure it's helpful for English language learners TBH. A bit of a red herring.

Comment: [Collins Dictionary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grammatical-word) **grammatical word** (noun) *- another name for **function word***.

Comment: Oh, come on, @BillJ, I guess all words have a meaning as well, including _the_, don't they?

Comment: Most do, but items like subordinators and coordinators are just meaningless markers. And grammaticised prepositions have little if any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, there are *issues* with that Wikipedia article.

As with many confusions in English grammar, this can be traced to people trying to think about English using terms adapted for Latin.  In Latin, the subject of a verb can be indicated by the form of the verb (amo = I love, amas = you love etc)  So there are some words in English that don't translate to words in Latin, but to elements of Lating morphology.  And since, in Latin, morphology is much more important than syntax, such words seem to be "words that do grammar".  They don't have any "meaning" (since meaning is understood to be the translation of the word to Latin).

This is all a bit confused, because English isn't Latin...

All words have functions, all words have some content. It may be useful to contrast words like "cat", "eat", "big" with words like "I", "will", "the". The most common terms for these are "content or lexical" words, contrasted with "functional or grammatical" words.  But be aware that these labels are   just labels. It may also be better to analyse at the morpheme level, rather than at the level of words. All morphemes have functions. Lexical morphemes can give meaning on their own.  Functional morphemes are normally attached to lexical ones.  New lexical morphemes can be created, ad hoc.  New functional morphemes develop much more rarely.  But there are grey areas, and words can move from one category to another.  For example, "will" is primarily used to indicate a future time.  But it still has a lexical sense.

Reading: https://www.thoughtco.com/content-lexical-word-1689918